# What is the best UI element for selecting OPTION 1, OPTION 2 or NONE?

Tags: gui-design, design-patterns, selection, select

I am designing a very long form with around 40% of fields being a dropdown with options:

- [NOTHING SELECTED]
- Enabled (On / True)
- Disabled (Off / False)

The [NOTHING SELECTED] option is important, and different    than choosing either of the other two. 
 I am leaning towards    Segmented Button: (NOTHING) - (ENABLED) - (DISABLED). But not too    happy with it. 
 Having a Radio Button with Enable and Disable    that allows choosing one or none seems kinda misleading to me.    
 Any other noteworthy approaches? Patterns that are widely    recognised and accepted? 
 Thank you!